# Symfony 4.1 - App works only if cache deleted

Tags: symfony

when I start my application an error message comes up: `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

Now I clean my cache by `rm -rf /var/cache/dev` and call same url: it works.

Then I call the page again, same error: `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

The page works whenever I deleted the cache completely.

What's my problem?

Comment: Have you check your logs into var/log/ directory ?

Comment: There are no logs written.

Comment: try this : `./bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=dev -v`

Comment: Same problem. When I execute the command I can call the application. Further calls lead to the mentioned problem.

Comment: and restarting your `php-fpm` ?...

Comment: Also not helped :-(

Comment: Here's the problem: $ this-> dispatcher-> dispatch (KernelEvents :: REQUEST, $ event); (HttpKernel.php: handleRaw)

Comment: Maybe there is a recursive problem?

Comment: Do you have the xdebug php extension enabled?

Comment: Xdebug is not supported.
php -v
PHP 7.2.12-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Nov 12 2018 09:55:44) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.12-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

Comment: I also have a cackePHP application on the server. Here is everything great. No problems...

Comment: try this into `bin/console`, set this :  `ini_set('memory_limit','-1');`

Comment: clear the cache after this*

Comment: I did, no success... same problem.

Comment: It is also strange that no errors are generated. Neither in the symfony log nor in the apache log.

Comment: it work for another page or it's the same ?

Comment: Always the same (all pages). 

The application is the symfony demo (https://github.com/symfony/demo).

1. Call http://192.168.11.11/de/login
> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

2. Clear cache!!!
3. Call http://192.168.11.11/de/login
> Page works!!!

4. Call http://192.168.11.11/de/login
> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

...

5. Call http://192.168.11.11/de/blog/
> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

6. Clear cache!!!
7. Call http://192.168.11.11/de/blog/
> Page works!!!

8. Call http://192.168.11.11/de/blog/
> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

...

But why?

Comment: Could it be that you cache gets owned by some other user and server just could not read from it? Also, from you question you removed `/var/cache/dev`, but I assume the leading `/` is a typo?

Comment: Is your APP_ENV set to dev? If it's prod you won't get as many debugging info as with dev.

Comment: The write permissions are to the whole application chmod -R 777 and the user and group ist set to www-data. To delete the cache I mean rm -rf var/cache/dev

Comment: It works now. I've installed composer require symfony/apache-pack